# Movement relative to a plane

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, webgl

I have an issue with my current camera code.  In my app, I can rotate the model that is being viewed, but also need to be able to "walk" the model.  This means that the user can change the relative orientation of the model, but walking and rotating still needs to be done relative to the plane of the model.

For instance, imagine looking at the model head on, like a building, such that you see the side of the building.  If the user presses "W" in this case, they will move closer to the building.  Now, they could choose to rotate the model's pitch such that they are now looking at the roof of the model (or the user could choose to go up high then look down at the ground).  In this case, hitting "W" needs to maintain the existing altitude, and move forward "up" towards the top of the screen.  In general, the motion needs to feel as though you are walking relative to the plane of the model, even if the plane as been rotated relative to your point of view.

The same problem exists with looking right and left.  Suppose you are again looking at the side of the building, and hit the arrow keys to look right or left.  The rotation at this point is in the same plane as the model.  But if the user rotates the pitch of the model to look at the roof, then they look right, it rotates about the camera's position instead, and looks like the model rotated away, rather than just spinning around.  Imagine just standing on the ground looking down.  Rotation of the camera would look like the world is spinning, but that's not what I get.  I get the model rotating away, as though you rotate your eye to look towards the sky.

Here is my update function

```
    mat4.identity(this.eyeMatrix);
    mat4.identity(this.orbitMatrix);
    mat4.identity(this.mvMatrix);

    mat4.fromRotationTranslation(eyeMatrix,   this.eyeRotation,   [0, 0, 0]);
    mat4.fromRotationTranslation(orbitMatrix, this.orbitRotation, [0, 0, 0]);       

    mat4.translate(this.mvMatrix, this.mvMatrix, this.orbit);
    mat4.multiply(this.mvMatrix,  this.mvMatrix, this.orbitMatrix);
    mat4.translate(this.mvMatrix, this.mvMatrix, this.eye);
    mat4.multiply(this.mvMatrix,  this.mvMatrix, this.eyeMatrix);

    this.getModelViewMatrix();
    this.getProjectionMatrix();
    this.getNormalMatrix();
```

Where orbit and eye are vec3's, orbit and eye matrix are mat4's, and eyeRotation and orbitRotation are quaternions.

I have this for changing orbit orientation:

```
    this.orbitYaw   += yawAmount;
    this.orbitPitch += pitchAmount;

    var orbitRotation = this.orbitRotation;

    var rotPitch = this.createOrbitPitchRotation();
    quat.copy(orbitRotation, rotPitch);

    var rotYaw = quat.create();
    quat.setAxisAngle(rotYaw, this.up, this.orbitYaw);
    quat.multiply(orbitRotation, rotYaw, orbitRotation);

    this.update();
```

I have this for changing eye orientation:

```
    var rotYaw = quat.create();
    quat.setAxisAngle(rotYaw, this.up, yawAmount);
    quat.multiply(this.eyeRotation, rotYaw, this.eyeRotation);

    quat.rotateX(this.eyeRotation, this.eyeRotation, pitchAmount);
    quat.normalize(this.eyeRotation, this.eyeRotation);

    this.update();
```

And finally, I have this for changing eye position (forward):

```
 function moveEye(direction, velocity) {
    vec3.scale(direction, direction, velocity);
    vec3.add(this.eye, this.eye, direction);
    this.update();
};

function moveEyeForward(velocity) {
    var dir   = vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 0);
    var right = this.getEyeRightVector();

    vec3.cross(dir, right, this.up);
    vec3.normalize(dir, dir);

    this.moveEye(dir, velocity);

    this.update();
};

function getEyeRightVector() {
    var q  = this.eyeRotation;
    var qx = q[0], qy = q[1], qz = q[2], qw = q[3];

    var x = 1 - 2 * (qy * qy + qz * qz);
    var y =     2 * (qx * qy + qw * qz);
    var z =     2 * (qx * qz - qw * qy);

    return vec3.fromValues(x, y, z);
};
```

**So the question is, how do I ensure that eye motion is always relative to the plane of the model (relative to plane of orbit rotation)?**

...

Comment: If you want to move independently from the view direction, why not just do something like `moveEye(vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 1), velocity)` in `moveEyeForward`?

Comment: It needs to move in the plane of the model.  Moving in the z direction would move along the plane of the model so long as the plane of the model is parallel to the z axis.  But if the model gets rotated such that the "up" direction of the model is parallel to the z axis, then moving the eye along z would cause an apparent motion "down" to the model, rather than along the ground.

Comment: Then multiply the direction vector with the model's world matrix.